# Why can the Rust compiler not optimize away the Err arm of Box::downcast?

Tags: assembly, optimization, rust, compiler-optimization, llvm-codegen

I have a `Box<dyn Any>` and I know the underlying type so I want to optimize away the test in [`Box::downcast()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.downcast) ([source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.28.0/src/liballoc/boxed.rs#L471)).

First I tried with [`std::hint::unreachable_unchecked()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/hint/fn.unreachable_unchecked.html):

```
pub unsafe fn downcast() -> Box<i32> {
    let value = any();
    if let Ok(value) = value.downcast() {
        value
    } else {
        std::hint::unreachable_unchecked()
    }
}
```

and

```
pub unsafe fn downcast() -> Box<i32> {
    any().downcast().map_err(|_| std::hint::unreachable_unchecked()).unwrap()
}
```

with `rustc -C opt-level=3` both result in this (40 lines omitted):

```
example::downcast:
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 16
        call    any@PLT
        mov     rbx, rax
        mov     qword ptr [rsp], rax
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 8], rdx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    qword ptr [rdx + 24]
        mov     rax, rbx
        add     rsp, 16
        pop     rbx
        ret
        mov     rbx, rax
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    core::ptr::drop_in_place
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    _Unwind_Resume@PLT
        ud2
```

Since this is not the optimization I was looking for, I tried

```
pub unsafe fn downcast() -> Box<i32> {
    let value = any();
    std::intrinsics::assume(value.is::<i32>());
    value.downcast().unwrap()
}
```

but this got even worse (118 lines omitted):

```
example::downcast:
        push    r15
        push    r14
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 32
        call    any@PLT
        mov     rbx, rax
        mov     r14, rdx
        mov     qword ptr [rsp], rax
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 8], rdx
        mov     r15, qword ptr [rdx + 24]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    r15
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 16], rbx
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 24], r14
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    r15
        movabs  rcx, -5015437470765251660     ;TypeId::of::<i32>()
        cmp     rax, rcx
        jne     .LBB5_7
        mov     rax, rbx
        add     rsp, 32
        pop     rbx
        pop     r14
        pop     r15
        ret
.LBB5_7:
        mov     rdi, rbx
        mov     rsi, r14
        call    core::result::unwrap_failed
        ud2
        mov     rbx, rax
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 16]
        call    core::ptr::drop_in_place
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    _Unwind_Resume@PLT
        ud2
        mov     rbx, rax
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    core::ptr::drop_in_place
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    _Unwind_Resume@PLT
        ud2
```

I expected to generate code like this, which is the `Ok` arm from `Box::downcast`:

```
pub unsafe fn downcast() -> Box<i32> {
    let value = any();
    let raw: *mut dyn Any = Box::into_raw(value);
    Box::from_raw(raw as *mut i32)
}
```

which results in this (**zero** lines omitted):

```
example::downcast:
        push    rax
        call    any@PLT
        pop     rcx
        ret
```

Why can the compiler not optimize the code in such a way?

All assembly [generated by godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/E49KP0).

Comment: "I expected to generate code like this, which is the `Ok` arm from `Box::downcast`:" -- Before the `Ok` arm, there is one call that you're omitting: `self.is::<T>()`. If you insert that call there, even if you discard the result (so `let value = any(); value.is::<i32>(); let raw: ...`), you'll get the same code. I don't know yet what specifically in its implementation it is that is difficult to optimise away.

Comment: @hvd 

That's the statement which I know is true and expect the compiler to optimize away

Comment: I think the virtual call to `any::get_type_id()` inside `self.is::<T>()` being preserved.  The compiler must not be able to see through it, and leaves it in in case it has side effects, along with an unwind block.

Comment: @wartmanm I just read your comment after researching and posting my answer... Would've saved me a bunch of work :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to optimize your code as good as we can manually. If we manually inline `downcast()` we get the following:

```
pub unsafe fn downcast() -> Box<i32> {
    let value = any();
    if value.is::<i32>() {
        let raw: *mut Any = Box::into_raw(value);
        Box::from_raw(raw as *mut i32)
    } else {
        std::hint::unreachable_unchecked()
    }
}
```

We can transform this:

```
pub unsafe fn downcast() -> Box<i32> {
    let value = any();
    value.is::<i32>();
    let raw: *mut Any = Box::into_raw(value);
    Box::from_raw(raw as *mut i32)
}
```

`value.is::<i32>()` is unused! Can we remove it? Here's lies the issue.

The `is` method calls `get_type_id` on a `dyn Any` object. That method can only be determined at runtime. And **it may have side effects**. Thus it can **not** be removed.

You can see the same lengthy assembly code as in your examples just from the following function:

```
#![feature(get_type_id)]
pub fn nop(any: Box<dyn Any>) {
    any.get_type_id();
}
```

---

Now you may argue that `Any::get_type_id` is universally defined by the compiler and can not be overridden, but the compiler isn't smart enough to realize that.